# How read and search multiple txt files in listBox with (in) one button c#?

Tags: c#, io

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.txt*", 
            SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string file in allfiles)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
            listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file)); 
        }
    }
}
```

There is listbox1 with all .txt files from direcory and subfolder...

Now I need from this listBox all files and search by some string.

Can I iterate loop and read file by file?
I don't have an idea how read and search files, need I open first, then store a data of file somewhere, maybe list or listView?

Comment: Please try to narrow your question down to a single one. "Can I …" is not really a good question because you can just try it and find out. If your attempt doesn't work, post your code and what you expected it to do and we can help out. Google is really helpful for things like "how do I read a text file in c#".

Comment: Search and do what with. This question needs a bit more work

Comment: Note that in the code above you appear to be "throwing away" the directory path that was used to get the file names (`fbd.SelectedPath`). You might want to save that for later if you intend on opening all the files and searching through them.

Comment: Also, take a look at the [`System.IO.File`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjk7tz5wuLiAhXXjp4KHZWaBNYQFjAAegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.io.file&usg=AOvVaw0fvvVCGV5LK0gvtqmN0XZm) class. It has lots of handy methods for reading and writing text files.

Comment: @RufusL I want iterate listBox and search all items of listBox by input some string over textField. Is that possible? I’m novice in programming, sorry for maybe dumb question. 

Comment: Yes, you can iterate over the `Items` collection of a `ListBox`. Other than that, I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking. What do you want to do with the items and the search string? What is the overall goal?

Comment: Of course its possible, being a beginner though its not an excuse for a poorly explained question or is it an excuse for not at least trying to break down your problems and attack it step at a time

Comment: @RufusL search each file content for entered search string. Once the search is over, the applications need to show all file which contain search string ( show a list of files ) along with number of repetition of said string. Sorry for poorly explained question.

Comment: I think we've given you everything you need to get started. 1. Save `fbd.SelectedPath` in a class field so you have it for later (depending on where you are executing this search code). 2. For each file name in `listBox1.Items`, concatenate the path from #1 with the name to get the full path (`Path.Combine(savedPath, filename)`) 3. Use the `File` class to read the text file (like `File.ReadAllLines(fullFilePath)`). Search for "how to read a text file c#" for more info, give it a shot, and update your question with something more specific (or ask a new one) if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would use a class of its own to store your search results. When we search files, and if we find the keyword we're searching for, we'd create an object of this class and at it to a list. Something like this:

```
public class SearchResults
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string SearchWord { get; set; }
    public int Occurences { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use the `System.IO.File` class to read your files. Remember this is not the only way, but merely one way of doing it. Here I have a list of file names, which is equivalent to the array you have in your program.

```
var searchTerm = "Hello";

var fileList = new List<string>() { "A.txt", "B.txt", "C.txt" };
var resultList = new List<SearchResults>();

// Iterate through files. You already are doing this.
foreach (var file in fileList)
{
    // Check to see if file exists. This is a second line of defense in error checking, not really necessary but good to have.
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        // Read all lines in the file into an array of strings.
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        // In this file, extract the lines contain the keyword
        var foundLines = lines.Where(x => x.Contains(searchTerm));
        if (foundLines.Count() > 0)
        {
            var count = 0;
            // Iterate each line that contains the keyword at least once to see how many times the word appear in each line
            foreach (var line in foundLines)
            {
                // The CountSubstring helper method counts the number of occurrences of a string in a string.
                var occurences = CountSubstring(line, searchTerm);
                count += occurences;
            }
            // Add the result to the result list.
            resultList.Add(new SearchResults() { FilePath = file, Occurences = count, SearchWord = searchTerm });
        }
    }
}
```

The `CountSubstring()` helper method.

```
public static int CountSubstring(string text, string value)
{
    int count = 0, minIndex = text.IndexOf(value, 0);
    while (minIndex != -1)
    {
        minIndex = text.IndexOf(value, minIndex + value.Length);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```